# How do I use keyring with Python 2.4?

Tags: python, python-2.4, python-keyring

I wrote a package that has dependency in keyring.

Everything is installed fine with Python 2.7 until I test Python 2.4

Here is my `setup.py`

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="blah",
    version='0.9dev',
    description="blah",
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=[
        'setuptools',
        'keyring',
        'argparse',
        'Cheetah'
    ],
    entry_points = """
    [console_scripts]
    A = A:main
    """,
)
```

I keep getting syntax error.
**UPDATE**: here is what i see when i try to install the package

```
Getting distribution for 'keyring'.
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hg/last-message.txt'
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keyring/tests/test_backend.py", line 65
    yield
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keyring/tests/test_core.py", line 127
    with open(self.legacy_location, 'w') as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/keyring/util/escape.py", line 21
    return c if c in LEGAL_CHARS else ESCAPE_FMT % ord(c)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
keyring.core: module references __path__
keyring.tests.test_cli: module references __file__
  File "/home/bpm/Downloads/qc_processor/eggs/tmp4sN15a/keyring-0.8.1-py2.4.egg/keyring/tests/test_backend.py", line 65
    yield
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/home/bpm/Downloads/qc_processor/eggs/tmp4sN15a/keyring-0.8.1-py2.4.egg/keyring/tests/test_core.py", line 127
    with open(self.legacy_location, 'w') as f:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "/home/bpm/Downloads/qc_processor/eggs/tmp4sN15a/keyring-0.8.1-py2.4.egg/keyring/util/escape.py", line 21
    return c if c in LEGAL_CHARS else ESCAPE_FMT % ord(c)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The errors are due to using features that were added to Python after version 2.4, like the `with` statement and conditional expressions.  See, for instance, [the What's New document for Python 2.5](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html).

Comment: so how do i get keyring just for python 2.4?

Comment: I dunno for sure.  Assuming you are talking about the package here (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyring), the latest version listed is 0.8.1 and claims to be supported on 2.4.  The `setup.py` file you show is for 0.9dev so presumably the latest development version.  You could try installing an older version.

Comment: The only version of keyring I was able to use with Python 2.4.x is v0.5, available at https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/k/keyring/keyring-0.5.tar.gz